# Applications in Dock not showing 'open application' indicators

Tags: macos, high-sierra, dock

Since up grading to High Sierra 10.13.6 I've had all sorts of issues, one of them is:

Being unable to tell which apps are open in the dock on my MacBook Pro. The black tags/arrow heads showing which apps are in use are gone!

How can you tell which Apps are open in the Dock now? Really really annoying problem and I can't see a fix anywhere.

Comment: I'm running High Sierra on my iMac. When I have an application open, a small white dot appears underneath the application icon in the dock.

Answer (score 9):

System Preferences > Dock

Is ‘Show indicators for open applications’ checked?

Checking that should fix your problem with the Dock.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the default behavior (showing indicators) for decades now has been changed without notice, and it's up to users to figure out how to get it back?

Comment: @MechMK1 this answer makes no such claim.

Comment: The way the question was asked seemed to me as if the behaviour was changed by the update. It might have been changed by the user, too, hence my question.